# How to get all documents after database connection has been made

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB.  Here is my setup

```
// backend/server.js

const dbRoute = mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1]/[database];

mongoose.connect(
  dbRoute,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
); 

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the database"));
```

I am getting the console log message in the terminal. so I'm connected.  I don't have the schema and this `dbRoute` is read only.  How can get all the documents and save it to my local mongoDB ?

Comment: can you be little more specific? like you want to find all docs from a particular `collection` or using a model or something?

Comment: You have a long path to go, I invite yo to dig a little more into mongodb documentation https://www.mongodb.com/